# Telco obligations on cable going across driveway (New Zealand)

Tags: new-zealand, easement

I have a cable with phone lines on a pole across outside my house going across my driveway.Occasionally I have large trucks which need to come into my property but are unable to do so because the truck is higher then the cable.  (most vehicles have no problem getting in-and-out - the truck in question is particularly tall/large.)

Does anyone know if I can legally compel the Telco to either raise or bury the cables, and if so, at whose expense is this likely to be?  (Of-course I'll be nice - I just want to know where I stand before I engage).   Relatedly, if someone is liable to me on this obligation, is it reasonable to assume its the lines company, or do I have recourse against the council as well?

Other information that might be relevant -

- The property is located rurally in greater Auckland.
- The cables existed prior to me purchasing the property (ie more then 5 years ago)
- There is nothing I am aware of on the property file about any rights of easement.  Maybe because this is technically council property?

I'm not sure where to find the appropriate law.  I have found [the Property Law Act 2007](https://www.legislation.govt.nz/act/public/2007/0091/latest/whole.html#DLM969488) but I don't know if it applies (I'm guessing the berm is not my property??) or exactly how to read it.    Schedule 5 talks about Covenants implied of grants of vehicular rights of way (including Schedule 5 (1)(2) talks about the right to "That right to go, pass, and re-pass is exercisable at all times, by day and by night, and is exercisable with or without vehicles, machinery, and equipment **of any kind.**"  (emphasis mine)

Comment: Is this line on your property or the public footpath?

Comment: @DaleM On the public footpath would be a closer description. Its not on my property, even  though I am expected to maintain it + so its in council property.  There is no footpath, but I'm not asked for permission before other utilities were added (buried) or when they added road signage to it.